# How to control feature image size using only CSS

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a hard time trying to solve this problem. I don't want WP controlling the size of my images, so I stopped it from generating image sizes setting all values in Settings>>Media to 0. Also, my functions.php doesn't have any `add_image_size()`. This should be enough but WP is still getting width and height from somewhere.

My code:

```
<div class="post-image-div"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-post')); ?></div>
```

CSS:

```
.post-image-div {
 width: 100% 
}
.img-post {
 max-width: 100%;
 heigth: auto;
}
```

The output:

```
<img src="" class="img-post" alt="" width="128" height="86">
```

What is preventing my code from working is the "width" and "height" WP is adding in `<img>`. I don't know from where WP is generating these values.

Comment: did you set a size for thumbnails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the original image as output then use

```
// Full resolution (original size uploaded)
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array('class' => 'img-post')); ?>
```

Instead of

```
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-post'));
```

I hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-post'));
```